# Sorting numbers in a list - Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

Say I had lists that I wanted to sort - numbers from highest to lowest - that contained both names and numbers, for example:

```
A = ["LA" , 10 , 3 , 4]  #lists ending with a comma after the closing bracket are interpreted as tuples containing a list
B = ["NY" , 4 , 2 , 2] #need quotes around the AK, etc
C = ["AK" , 1 , 4 , 6] ,
D = ["WA" , 7 , 9 , 2] ,
```

How would I sort these lists to make the numbers go in a descending order (highest to lowest)?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is that your actual code? You might be surprised to find that A,B,C, and D aren't lists. They're tuples, each containing one element.

Comment: This is not my code, however I was just using this as an example. Please consider that I am new to coding.

Comment: Hey Steve--Welcome to SO and coding!  Helpful hint, both for your own development and for getting good answers:  Make sure your posts contain a description of the problem, what you've tried, what you expected to get, and what you got instead (sometimes you'll find just by writing a good question, you'll figure out the answer yourself!).

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks very much for the welcome. I'll do as you say in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For descending order; *(texts will come first)*

```
>>> import numbers
>>> import sys

>>> A = ["LA", 10, 3, 4]
>>> print sorted(A, key=lambda n: n if isinstance(n, numbers.Number) else sys.float_info.max, reverse=True)
['LA', 10, 4, 3]
```

For ascending order; *(texts will come first)*

```
>>> print sorted(A, key=lambda n: n if isinstance(n, numbers.Number) else sys.float_info.min, reverse=False)
['LA', 3, 4, 10]
```

For descending order; *(texts will come last)*

```
>>> print sorted(A, key=lambda n: n if isinstance(n, numbers.Number) else sys.float_info.min, reverse=True)
[10, 4, 3, 'LA']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
a=['gg', 10, 1, 100, 55]
def myKey(x):
   if isinstance(x,str):
       return -99999999
   else:
       return x #or -1 * key if you want the numbers in reverse order
a.sort(key=myKey)
reversed(a) #will give you a in reversed order -- string at the end
```

The key argument specifies a function that will be used to 'transform' each element into the key to be sorted.  The reversed iterator simply gives the elements in reverse order....

Comment: It says that basestring is not defined, why is that?

Comment: basestring and print as a statement are both python2 constructs.  They've been edited out...

Comment: This looks really good! It's in ascending order, how do I get it to go in descending order? Is it key=reverse?

Comment: edited the answer -- what are you planning to do with this code?

Comment: The post appeared in the Low Quality Posts review line. Probably because it is code only without explanation. I didn't downvote, but I guess to prevent further downvotes you could add a bit of textual explanation what the code does.

Comment: Thanks!  Is it still there?  I added some explanatory text...